# Registering custom\additional routes for a laravel websocket server?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

So I'm using `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` to setup a WS server and I want to work with multiple apps so I did this in `config\websockets.php`:

```php
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('A_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('A_APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('A_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('A_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('A_APP_PATH'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
    [
        'id' => env('B_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('B_APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('B_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('B_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('B_APP_PATH'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

However, I want to implement custom handlers for each app and I've been trying this, `routes\web.php`:

```php
WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('app/{appKey}/bapp', \App\WebSockets\BAppWebSocketHandler::class);

//Also tried this..
WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('app/{appKey}', \App\WebSockets\AAppWebSocketHandler::class);
//and created `AAppWebSocketHandler` which does nothing but calling parent (WebSocketHandler) methods
```

Problem is it's always using one handler for all apps despite the difference in routes.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define routes while defining multiple apps in the config. Instead configure Echo to work with separate app key and secret. If you want to use custom handler with own logic, then remove them from configs. Also note that, you won't get any channel or pusher client library support. You will have to implement your own authentication as well.